# jquery dialogue issue in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a webform where i am entering data and displaying minimal data in a gridview, so far so good,Now i had a requirement to to edit data in gridview ,and editing should be done in a popup window.I thought of to use same form for edit and add data.Can we do it in same form for adding and jquery dialogue for Editing??.As of now i did following way.The issue i am facing is when i click Edit button in gridview, Jquery dilogue will come and after updating if i close it, the the form is displayed with only gridview,  Part which i reused it for editing is disappeared in the Adding section.Is there any way to maintain the form like if i close the jquery dialogue, i should get the Adding form and grid view with data where i started editing.As of now what i did is in the close event of jquery i refreshed page by using `location.reload(true);` ,but by doing this i will lose the data in  gridview and form which i was editing.This is what i have done

```
     <div id="idTestForm">
            <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 11pt; color: white; background-color: #6699ff;">
                <div>
                    Leaf Details
                </div>
            </div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnlForm" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
<div class="divTable" style="padding-top: 5px">
                        <div class="divRow">
                            <div class="divCell">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblRegionCode" Text="Region Code:" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="divCell">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpRegionCode" Width="150px" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpRegionCode_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <div class="divCell">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblleafId" Text="Bsc Id:" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="divCell">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLeafId" Width="150px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
</div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="btnClear_Click" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
 <div id="divGrdBsc">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnlGrid" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div style="padding-top: 15px; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotalCount" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="divRow" style="padding-top: 40px">
                    <div class="divCell">
                        <asp:GridView ID="grdLeaf" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BSC_ID,BSC_NAME,REGION_CODE,TECH_CODE,VENDOR_CODE,
                            EXCHANGE_CODE,STATUS_CODE,BSC_LOCATION"
                            CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowCommand="grdBsc_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grdBsc_RowDataBound">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                            <Columns>
```

Above only few input controls i posted ,actually there are many and after saving data it will be displayed in gridview

After this when some one clicked Gridvew edit button ,in the row command i called javascript shown below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showBscDetails() {
        $("#idTestForm").dialog({
            open: function () {
                $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass("ui-state-error");
            },
            title: 'Leaf Details',
            appendTo: "form",
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: true,
            show: 'blind',
            hide: 'blind',
            width: 1100,
            height: 600
        }).prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background", "#6A7667");
        $("#idTestForm").on('dialogclose', function (event) {

            location.reload(true);


        });
    }
```

Comment: Can any body post an example where we can do edit and add by using single form and a popup window??

Comment: To do what you're doing I use a popup dialog called [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) that, for the purposes of editing opens a popup `iframe` with a `src` that refers to a standalone .aspx form with it's own code behind that handles the edits. I configure the colorbox to call `__doPostBack()` on close so I can rebind the gridview.

Comment: How to do __doPostBack() to rebind gridview.i thought of to do same logic in existing jquery dialogue code

Comment: `__doPostBack()` takes 2 string arguments, the event target and the event argument, which populates 2 hidden fields, `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT` which can be checked in the Page.Load event.  when you see the target you specify you know you need to make a call to `grdLeaf.Databind()`.  e.g.: `__doPostBack('grdLeafEditComplete', '');` then in Page.Load check `Request('__EVENTTARGET') == 'grdLeafEditComplete'` and call databind if true

Comment: As of now grid is populating with correct edited data,i did rebind after edit,but the real problem i am missing the section where we can add data which is reused in jquery dialougue

Comment: are you saying want to "pre-populate" the fields in the edit dialog with data  from the selected row of the grid before the popup displays?

Comment: Grid is coming with edited data ,but the section i used for adding new data is missing.Because i used same section in jquery dialogue poppup for editing which is div id idTestForm

Comment: I am rebinding data,my real issue and question is can we reuse a section in webform for adding on same form and editing in jquery dialogue popup

Comment: You should be able to add or edit using the same form.  However, you need to make sure you have a way of differentiating an "Add" command from an "Edit" command because you only have one button on your dialog.

Comment: @fnostro in my code behind i  managed everything nicely, so need to worry about update and add.But my real issue is after editing if i close jquery dialogue and come back to the form i am missing the section of adding which is reused for editing and only displaying the updated gridview

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _"missing the section of adding"_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109475/discussion-between-fnostro-and-peter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i fixed the issue.What i did is i created a Usercontrol contains the common controls used for adding and editing and reused the user controls in a single page.Simpleee and everything in a seperate update panels:)